# A generalized Alexandroff space that is not an Alexandroff space

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

A topological space $(X,T)$ is called *generalized Alexandroff* if any intersection of open sets is generalized open (where $A$ is *generalized open* if its interior contains all closed subsets of $A$). It's clear from definition that every [Alexandroff space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandrov_topology) is generalized Alexandroff. But the converse needn't be true, I need an example to show this.

Comment: What is "generalized open"?

Comment: A nonempty subset A of X is called generalized open if its interior contains every closed subset of A.

Comment: Consider $ω + 1$ with final segment topology.

Comment: @user87690: That’s an Alexandroff space.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I wasn't clear, I meant strict final segnents: $(α, \rightarrow)$ for $α ∈ ω + 1$, so it works like in your example with $ω$ instead of $ω_1$.

Comment: Why did this question receive so many downvotes? It seems okay to me.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\omega_1+1$. The open sets of $X$ are $\varnothing$ and the sets $[\alpha,\omega_1]$ for $\alpha<\omega_1$. Every intersection of open sets is either open or $\{\omega_1\}$, which is generalized open but not open.